# GetPropertiesFor ajax call from Sharepoint 2013 app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, user-profile-service, rest

I tried the below code with GetMyProperties in a SharePoint Hosted app and it works, but the following code gives me a bad request

```
    url = appweburl +
    "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\user'"
     method: "GET",
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: successHandler,
     error: errorHandler
```

But it gives me a bad request... Please help me

Comment: found it, it was "domain\\user" error... missed the extra backslash

Comment: Add this as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommended to utilize [encodeURIComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aeh9cef7%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) in order to encode `accountName` for `GetPropertiesFor` method.

```
function getUserProfile(accountName,success,error)
{
   var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;  
   $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: error
    });
}

//Usage
var accountName = 'i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'; 
getUserProfile(accountName,function(entity){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(entity));     
},
function(data){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));     
})
```